# CommentedMap.update() not preserving comments

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm not sure I'm tackling this problem from the right angle so please let me know should you see another way.

Using ruamel.yaml module, I want to have a representation of a few configuration files before dumping them back with their comments preserved.

For this I basically have :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

from ruamel.yaml import YAML
class MyYaml():
  def __init__(self, cm):
    self.yaml = YAML()
    self.yaml.default_flow_style = False
    self.cm = cm
    
  def load_main_config_file(self, path):
    if isinstance(path, str):
      with open(path, 'r') as config_file:
        self.cm.update(self.yaml.load(config_file))
        # cannot be self.cm = self.yaml.load(config_file)
        # because it would change the id of self.cm
        # the dict would not be accessible from outside anymore
        
  def load_config_file(self, path_key_list, target_dict = None):
    for file_path,key_list in path_key_list:
      with open(file_path, 'r') as config_file:
        self.update_dict((target_dict if target_dict is not None else self.cm), key_list, self.yaml.load(config_file))
        
  def update_dict(self, my_dict, key_list, value):
    """
    Works fine to preserve comments but cannot be used for the main config file as the dict is empty
    """
    for k in key_list[:-1]:
      my_dict = my_dict.setdefault(k, {})
    my_dict[key_list[-1]] = value
    
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap 
from copy import deepcopy
class Parent():
  def __init__(self):
    self.__cm = CommentedMap() # private so users cannot modify
    self.Yaml = MyYaml(self.__cm)

  @property
  def cm(self):
    return deepcopy(self.__cm)
    
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys
class Child(Parent):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    yaml = YAML()
    self.Yaml.load_main_config_file("path_to_file")
    print("\n\n############################")
    print("Main load : ")
    print("############################")
    yaml.dump(self.cm, sys.stdout)
    print("\n\n############################")
    print("Other load :")
    print("############################")
    self.Yaml.load_config_file([("path_to_file",["other_file"])])
    yaml.dump(self.cm, sys.stdout)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
   ch = Child()
```

And I get this output :

```
############################
Main load :
############################
key1: val1
key2: val2
key3:
  key31: val31
  key32: val32

key4:
  key41: val41


############################
Other load :
############################
key1: val1
key2: val2
key3:
  key31: val31
  key32: val32

key4:
  key41: val41
other_file:
############
# ! TEST ! #
############
  key1: val1

# Comment 1
  key2: val2

#this is a comment
  key3:
    key31: val31
    key32: val32

  key4:
    key41: val41
```

Any suggestion so even the first config file preserves the comments?

PS : This is my first post on here, I hope it's clear enough. Thanks for your time !

Comment: I can sort of guess the input from analysing your code and its output, but I was too lazy to do so, so no full working and tested code in my answer like I normally do. Next time you post a question include everything needed for reproduction.

Comment: @anthon I knew I forgot something. I had it at first but then edited the code snippet. The input is exactly the content of self.cm["other_file"]. I load the same input twice

Comment: It was late last night and I hadn't even noticed the file contents to be the same.Tthe answer didn't work as first stated, I created the input, updated the code , so now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line:

```
  self.cm.update(self.yaml.load(config_file))
```

the `load()` returns a `CommentedMap()`, from which the update only uses the key
value pairs. If you want the comments copied over do:

```
  tmp_cm = self.yaml.load(config_file)
  self.cm.update(tmp_cm)
  tmp_cm.copy_attributes(self.cm)
```

If you want to preserve any already existing comments on self.cm, for keys
that are not going to be updated, you should inspect the `.ca` attribute and do
an update of the relevant items, instead of a full overwrite of the comments.

Please note that this "internal data" is not guaranteed to remain stable,
so pin your ruamel.yaml version, and test before changing that version.
You should also consider updating your Python version, as 3.5 is EOL
and support in ruamel.yaml will drop with the next minor version upgrade.

Full program:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

class MyYaml():
  def __init__(self, cm):
    self.yaml = YAML()
    self.yaml.default_flow_style = False
    self.cm = cm

  def load_main_config_file(self, path):
    if isinstance(path, str):
      with open(path, 'r') as config_file:
        tmp_cm = self.yaml.load(config_file)
        self.cm.update(tmp_cm)
        tmp_cm.copy_attributes(self.cm)
        # cannot be self.cm = self.yaml.load(config_file)
        # because it would change the id of self.cm
        # the dict would not be accessible from outside anymore
    
  def load_config_file(self, path_key_list, target_dict = None):
    for file_path,key_list in path_key_list:
      with open(file_path, 'r') as config_file:
        self.update_dict((target_dict if target_dict is not None else self.cm), key_list, self.yaml.load(config_file))
    
  def update_dict(self, my_dict, key_list, value):
    """
    Works fine to preserve comments but cannot be used for the main config file as the dict is empty
    """
    for k in key_list[:-1]:
      my_dict = my_dict.setdefault(k, {})
    my_dict[key_list[-1]] = value

from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap 
from copy import deepcopy
class Parent():
  def __init__(self):
    self.__cm = CommentedMap() # private so users cannot modify
    self.Yaml = MyYaml(self.__cm)

  @property
  def cm(self):
    return deepcopy(self.__cm)

from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys
class Child(Parent):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    yaml = YAML()
    self.Yaml.load_main_config_file("path_to_file")
    print("\n\n############################")
    print("Main load : ")
    print("############################")
    yaml.dump(self.cm, sys.stdout)
    print("\n\n############################")
    print("Other load :")
    print("############################")
    self.Yaml.load_config_file([("path_to_file",["other_file"])])
    yaml.dump(self.cm, sys.stdout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   ch = Child()
```

which gives:

```
############################
Main load : 
############################
key1: val1

# Comment 1
key2: val2

#this is a comment
key3:
  key31: val31
  key32: val32

key4:
  key41: val41


############################
Other load :
############################
key1: val1

# Comment 1
key2: val2

#this is a comment
key3:
  key31: val31
  key32: val32

key4:
  key41: val41
other_file:
  key1: val1

# Comment 1
  key2: val2

#this is a comment
  key3:
    key31: val31
    key32: val32

  key4:
    key41: val41
```

Please note that the comments in the "nested" file do not get indented, you
would have to walk over the individual comments and change their start column to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that! It works great now.

I'll have a look at the `.ca` attribute so I might only have a single load function.
I had noticed for the comment indentation, it's not critical but I'll work on it.
Have a great day and thanks for your work on this module and continuous support.